# SQL ANSI JOIN precedence

Tags: sql-server, mysql, oracle, postgresql, join

I have a query that looks like this:

```
    SELECT *
      FROM TBLA A
 LEFT JOIN TBLB B ON A.Col1 = B.Col2
RIGHT JOIN TBLC C ON B.Col3 = C.Col4
      JOIN TBLD D ON C.Col5 = D.Col6
```

In which order will the joins be resolved?  I'm most interested in SQL Server, and will mark an explanation for it as the answer, but am equally interested in the ANSI/ISO standard and how it works in the various RDBMS.

The reason for this question was to figure out why the results differed from this query

```
    SELECT *
      FROM TBLA A
CROSS JOIN TBLC C
 LEFT JOIN TBLB B ON A.Col1 = B.Col2 AND B.Col3 = C.Col4
      JOIN TBLD D ON C.Col5 = D.Col6
```

Comment: CROSS JOIN TBLC C in your second query is very different from RIGHT JOIN TBLC C in your first one. That alone is a huge difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Logically** the joins are resolved in the order of the `ON` clauses from left to right.

The output of each join is a virtual table that goes into the next join.

So for the query in your question the virtual table result of `A LJ B` is then right joined onto `C`. The join condition of `B.Col3 = C.Col4` will lose any null extended rows preserved by the original left join effectively turning the first join back into a inner join and the resulting virtual table (which preserves all rows from `C`) is then inner joined onto `D`.

So your initial query can be simplified as

```
SELECT *
FROM TBLA A
INNER JOIN TBLB B ON A.Col1 = B.Col2
RIGHT JOIN TBLC C ON B.Col3 = C.Col4
      JOIN TBLD D ON C.Col5 = D.Col6
```

Which is effectively the same as `(A IJ B) ROJ (C IJ D)`

The order of the `ON` clauses is not necessarily the same as the order the tables appear in the query. This could also be rewritten as `(C IJ D) LOJ (A IJ B)`

```
SELECT *
FROM   TBLC C
       INNER JOIN TBLD D
         ON C.Col5 = D.Col6
       LEFT JOIN TBLA A
                 INNER JOIN TBLB B
                   ON A.Col1 = B.Col2
         ON B.Col3 = C.Col4
```

The position of the on clauses means that the outer join is carried out between the two virtual tables resulting from  `(C IJ D)` and `(A IJ B)` rather than just on a single table.

In your second query conceptually the virtual table `A x C` is left joined onto B preserving the entire cartesian product then the result of that is joined onto `D` with the predicate `C.Col5 = D.Col6`. This eliminates any rows from the final result that do not inner join between `C` and `D` meaning it is equivalent to

```
SELECT *
FROM   TBLC C
       JOIN TBLD D
         ON C.Col5 = D.Col6
       CROSS JOIN TBLA A
       LEFT JOIN TBLB B
         ON A.Col1 = B.Col2
            AND B.Col3 = C.Col4
```

Comment: I'm not sure that the first one is `(A IJ B) ROJ (C IJ D)`. I think it's `((A IJ B) ROJ C) IJ D)`.

Comment: These two versions are equivalent in results but not syntactically.

Answer (score 3):

In PostgreSQL:

> Use parentheses if necessary to determine the order of nesting. In the
>   absence of parentheses, JOINs nest left-to-right. In any case JOIN
>   binds more tightly than the commas separating FROM items.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM